# Sum Variable in file txt C# Console

Tags: c#

i have a data stored in txt format, then the data is displayed. i want to get a total of QOH in the picture, i have a problem in the whole sum.

[image: data image]

```
public void DisTranswe()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("TransactionHistory\\weekend\\transcationhistory.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] data = str.Split('#');
            string id = data[0];
            string date = data[1];
            string qty = data[2];
            string payment = data[3];
            string note = data[4];

            //output
            Console.WriteLine("IdTransaksi");
            Console.WriteLine(id);
            Console.WriteLine("DateTransaksi");
            Console.WriteLine(date);
            Console.WriteLine("QOH");
            Console.WriteLine(qty);
            Console.WriteLine("TotalPayment");
            Console.WriteLine(payment);
            Console.WriteLine("Note");
            Console.WriteLine(note);

        }
        sr.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please provide the input text file in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add counter for your QOH, like this:

```
public void DisTranswe()
    {
        Console.Clear();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("TransactionHistory\\weekend\\transcationhistory.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
        int sum=0;
        while ((str = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] data = str.Split('#');
            string id = data[0];
            string date = data[1];
            string qty = data[2];
            string payment = data[3];
            string note = data[4];

            sum=sum+int.Parse(qty);

            //output
            Console.WriteLine("IdTransaksi");
            Console.WriteLine(id);
            Console.WriteLine("DateTransaksi");
            Console.WriteLine(date);
            Console.WriteLine("QOH");
            Console.WriteLine(qty);
            Console.WriteLine("TotalPayment");
            Console.WriteLine(payment);
            Console.WriteLine("Note");
            Console.WriteLine(note);


        }

        Console.WriteLine("SUM");
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
        sr.Close();
        fs.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
int qoh =
    File
        .ReadAllLines("TransactionHistory\\weekend\\transcationhistory.txt")
        .Sum(x => int.Parse(x.Split('#')[2]));
```

Comment: why reading the file a second time if you can sum up `QOH` in the first loop

Comment: @Toshi - The code provided didn't match the screenshot. It seemed to me that a one-liner would be more appropriate that trying to mix in with code that didn't seem to be production code. We're also dealing with small files so reading it a second time would more than likely come from the cache - there's no significant penalty.